# Facing issues with sqlalchemy+postgresql session management

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy with PostgreSQL and the Pyramid web framework. Here is my `models.py`:

```
engine = create_engine(db_url, pool_recycle=3600,
                       isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED")

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.bind = engine

class _BaseMixin(object):
    def save(self):
        session.add(self)
        session.commit()

    def delete(self):
        session.delete(self)
        session.commit()
```

I am inheriting both the Base and _BaseMixin for my models. For example:

```
class MyModel(Base, _BaseMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'MY_MODELS'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
```

The reason is that I would like to do something like

```
m = MyModel()
m.save()
```

I am facing weird issues with session all the time. Sample error messages include

1. InvalidRequestError: This session is in 'prepared' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction.
2. InvalidRequestError: A transaction is already begun.  Use subtransactions=True to allow subtransactions.

All I want to do is to commit what I have in the memory into the DB. But intermittently SQLAlchemy throws errors like described above and fails to commit.

Is there something wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** The problems is that you're sharing one `Session` object between threads. It fails, because `Session` object [is not thread-safe](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/contextual.html#thread-local-scope) itself.

#### What happens?

You create a Session object, which is bound to current thread (let's call it `Thread-1`). Then you closure it inside your `_BaseMixin`. Incoming requests are handled in the different threads (let's call them `Thread-2` and `Thread-3`). When request is handling, you call `model.save()`, which uses `Session` object created in `Thread-1` from `Thread-2` or `Thread-3`. Multiple requests can run concurrently, which together with thread-unsafe `Session` object gives you totally indeterministic behaviour.

#### How to handle?

When using `scoped_session()`, each time you create new object with `Session()` it will be bound to current thread. Furthermore if there is a session bound to current thread it will return you existing session instead of creating new one.

So you can move `session = Session()` from the module level to your `save()` and `delete()` methods. It will ensure, that you are always using session from current thread.

```
class _BaseMixin(object):
    def save(self):
        session = Session()
        session.add(self)
        session.commit()

    def delete(self):
        session = Session()
        session.delete(self)
        session.commit()
```

But it looks like duplication and also doesn't make sense to create `Session` object (it will always return the same object inside current thread). So SA provides you ability to [implicitly](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/contextual.html#implicit-method-access) access session for current thread. It produces clearer code.

```
class _BaseMixin(object):
    def save(self):
        Session.add(self)
        Session.commit()

    def delete(self):
        Session.delete(self)
        Session.commit()
```

Please, also note that for normal applications you **never** want to create `Session` objects explicitly. But want to use implicit access to thread-local session by using `Session.some_method()`.

#### Further reading

1. [Contextual/Thread-local Sessions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/contextual.html).
2. [When do I construct a `Session`, when do I commit it, and when do I close it?](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it).

Comment: That was very helpful